# RFID tags moving through a factory: How to expand timestamp data by minute?

Tags: r

**Issue:**

- I have about 9,000 rows of data that show XYZ data for about 10 tags.
- All tags ping at different rates. Some at 1 second, some at 7 seconds, some every few hours, and so on.
- I want to show how the tagged items move through a factory. Preferably with an animated GIF...

**Desired data set:**

- For each of the 10 tags, on a one minute interval, where is it in the factory? Some tags will have multiple records per minute. Some records will have hours since the last ping.

Is there a way to do this in R? I can brute force it with Excel (shutter) but I'm hoping someone can set me on the right path, even if it's the proper search term to send me on my journey. Thanks!

Comment: what code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Without an example data set to look at, there is a limit to what kind of answer I can provide.

However, the first thing that you want to do is get all of your observations on a unified time line. That is, each row should be a time stamp and each column should be the x, y, or z coordinate for one of your tags. Without seeing the data, I can't help you do this. Here are the types of things you need to think about. If tag A has measurements at timestamp 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 and tag B has measurements at timestamp 1 and 6, what value should tag B have for the measurements at timestamp 2, 3, 4, and 5. You could simply copy the value from timestamp 1 or you could do some type of interpolation between timestamp 1 and timestamp 6. If you don't know what I am talking about here, let me know.

Second, there could be package to make a gif in R. However, I have taken advantage of the R function `Sys.sleep`. Here is what I would suggest. Once you have your unified timeline for your dataset, write a for loop over the rows of your dataset. At the top of each row do `Sys.sleep(0.25)`. This will make R "sleep" for 0.25 seconds. Then plot the current row of the dataset for all of your tags. This creates a really cool video that you could record with some other tool.

Comment: I ended up using lubridate to make a frame with each minute in the range. I found two solutions from there. One with the rolling join from data.frame and another with tidyr sorting and using fill() to fill in the null values.